# Encoded PDF File Parsing

Tags: python, pdf-extraction

I am trying to parse PDF file to text. That file can be downloaded from official goverment site, but I spent hours trying to decode it. Adobe Extractor came close, but not really sure, If I can configure it to parse it properly
(https://developer.adobe.com/document-services/docs/overview/pdf-extract-api/quickstarts/python/). Adobe extract some of its text, but in wrong characters and only small portion.

This is the file : https://isir.justice.cz/isir/doc/dokument.PDF?id=49996138

Does somebody have any idea, how to extract it?

I am using python, but I guess any language will do, if it works.

Comment: There are tools like pypdfparser: https://py-pdf-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html

Comment: I see that you didnt open that file. That would work for basic PDFs, not for the one I posted. Try to copy some text from it, and you will understand.

Comment: I ran it through `ocrmypdf` (a free OCR tool on Linux) which gave output like `Zprava pro oddluzeni ao prezkumu

I]. Oznaéeni soudu a spisova znacka

Soudu

Méstskému soudu v Praze

Spis.znacka|

MSPH

90

INS.

16917

/ 2021
` (with line endings that you cannot see in a Stack Overflow comment). By no means perfect, especially regarding diacritics, but maybe still useful depending on what you want to do with it.